# Calling a .BAT file from another .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat file to which I can pass parameters.

```
LOAD_TABLE_WRAPPER.BAT Table1 DEV
```

Briefly, it runs an SQL to load Table1 on the Dev environment. Now, I want it to load multiple tables overnight. So, I set up a master .BAT which goes something like

```
::MASTER_LOAD.BAT
CALL LOAD_TABLE_WRAPPER.BAT Table1 Dev
CALL LOAD_TABLE_WRAPPER.BAT Table2 Dev
CALL LOAD_TABLE_WRAPPER.BAT Table3 Dev
```

If I submit MASTER_LOAD.BAT from cmd, it executes the load for Table1 but does not proceed to Table2 load. These are the last two lines of the WRAPPER.BAT

```
:eof
exit %ERROR_STATUS%
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `exit %error_status%` command in LOAD_TABLE_WRAPPER.BAT is terminating your batch session, so your MASTER_LOAD.BAT never gets a chance to resume with the next call.

You can fix the problem simply by adding the /B option to your EXIT command

```
exit /b %error_stats%
```

I almost never use EXIT without /B in a batch file (though there are times when /B is not wanted).

But another alternative is to run the called scripts via CMD instead of CALL.

```
::MASTER_LOAD.BAT
CMD /C LOAD_TABLE_WRAPPER.BAT Table1 Dev
CMD /C LOAD_TABLE_WRAPPER.BAT Table2 Dev
CMD /C LOAD_TABLE_WRAPPER.BAT Table3 Dev
```

There are a number of differences between the methods

**CALL with EXIT /B**

- Comparatively fast
- Can preserve environment variable values upon return (SETLOCAL is available if you don't want to preserve values)
- Called script inherits delayed expansion and extension states (enabled or disabled)

**CMD /C**

- Comparatively slow
- Cannot preserve environment variable values upon return. (You could write out the definitions to a file and load them back in upon returning to the master, but that is not convenient or efficient)
- Called script always starts with default delayed expansion and extension states (Normally delayed expansion is disabled and extensions are enabled)

I would never recommend using CMD /C over CALL unless the called batch files have EXIT without the /B option and you cannot modify the batch file to add the /B option.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the start command in order to solve this issue. Call makes the current process run the commands . You can learn more about start [here.](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) Basic implementation should be:

```
"START program-name arg1 arg2"`
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem in executing CALL LOAD_TABLE_WRAPPER.BAT Table1 Dev ? What is the result when you echo between the calls ?

Answer (score -1):

try to give a PAUSE command, like this :

`CALL LOAD_TABLE_WRAPPER.BAT Table1 Dev
PAUSE
CALL LOAD_TABLE_WRAPPER.BAT Table2 Dev
PAUSE
CALL LOAD_TABLE_WRAPPER.BAT Table3 Dev`