# Running batch file and del command won't work...?

Tags: batch-file

OK, to preface, I searched already and couldn't find a similar question, so I'm not sure what's going on here.

Basically, I want to rename a file in a subdirectory, copy a new file into that location, run a script there, then delete that new file and rename the old one to it's original name. The issue is it just stops at the delete command, and both files are left.  Here is my code (note the pauses are just in there for me to debug the script):

```
ren "C:\Users\me\Desktop\stuff\new\test.txt" "test(1).txt"
pause
copy "C:\Users\me\Desktop\stuff\test.txt" "C:\Users\me\Desktop\stuff\new\"
pause
"C:\Users\me\Desktop\stuff\new\sample.bat"
del "C:\Users\me\Desktop\stuff\new\test.txt"
pause
ren "C:\Users\me\Desktop\stuff\new\test(1).txt" "test.txt"
pause
```

Comment: Try `/q` parameter for `del`. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771049(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: It still just exited the script without deleting the file...

Comment: You need to use [`call`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732835(v=ws.11).aspx) to run one batch file from another and then return back to the main one.

Comment: @PM77-1 what if the the other batch file contains the `exit` command? I just tested and that will exit both scripts regardless of using `call` or not. **Edit:** [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799977/calling-a-bat-file-from-another-bat-file) relates to the issue I mentioned.

Comment: The lack of call was the issue.  Thank you PM